# After upgrading to Xcode 14.3, while trying to archive a Flutter app, I get "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: flutter, xcode

An existing Flutter project, built and archived many times before.

After upgrading Xcode to 14.3, while trying to archive the project, I get the following error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tried to clean, update pods etc. Nothing helps...

Any ideas?

Comment: Just checked flutter code once again, may be it shows any error in code.

Comment: we get this error `ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.f
    ramework" failed: No such file or directory (2)` when trying to archive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just modified the frameworks.sh in my Project adding the "**-f**" and pressed "Archive" in XCode, so it worked again.

/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
  fi
```

Answer (score 3):

[From the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725230)

> Workaround is to update all the generated ...-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, need to replace:
>
> ```
> source="$(readlink "${source}")"
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
> ```
>
> Seems this is CocoaPods issue...